# Generate Audio using a VTT as the text source with Google Text to Speech?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

For sign language videos, there is no audio already present normally; however, we do provide the VTT caption file for captioning into English.  The VTT does have a time-start and time-end for each text block of the cues.

I am wondering if it's possible to use the VTT as the text source to generate the Text to Speech audio, wherein the speed is controlled by the time codes in the caption file.

Currently not finding anything.  Usually it's the other way around--audio to subtitles--but I want to work subtitles to audio (US English).